# Launching a python file using an icon

Tags: python, tkinter

I have python file `gui1.py`. I want to execute it without terminal, By using an icon to launch the script `gui1.py`, which will prompt a [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html) window on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Make your file executable using below command

```
chmod +x gui1.py
```

Or Create a Bash file

```
vi rungui1.sh

#!/bin/bash
python gui1.py
```

then save it and make it executable

```
chmod +x rungui1.sh
```

Then follow these steps:

> Hit Alt+F2, type dconf-editor and hit Enter.
>
> In dconfg-editor goto: org ➤ gnome ➤ nautilus ➤ preferences
>
> Click on executable-text-activation and from drop down menu select:
>
> launch: to launch scripts as programs.

Comment: This is not working. I have already done that, it is still opening the file in gedit.

Comment: Check now i added one more method